# Use Python to calculate difference between date in current row and date in previous row and previous column

Tags: python, pandas, diff, calculation

I am trying to calculate the difference between dates in different rows that are not in the same column. I have the following dataset:

| Kiosk | Online | Offline | Online Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/5/2022 | 4 |
| 1 | 12/7/2022 | 12/17/2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 12/20/2022 | 12/21/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 12/24/2022 | 12/29/2022 | 5 |
| 2 | 11/15/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 15 |
| 2 | 12/2/2022 | 12/7/2022 | 5 |
| 2 | 12/15/2022 | 12/25/2022 | 10 |
| 3 | 10/30/2022 | 11/15/2022 | 16 |
| 3 | 11/17/2022 | 11/22/2022 | 5 |
| 3 | 11/23/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 7 |
| 3 | 12/4/2022 | 12/15/2022 | 11 |
| 3 | 12/18/2022 | 12/20/2022 | 2 |

I know I can use the diff function to calculate the difference between different rows in the same column, but I have not found a function that allows me to offset the row AND columns. In my example, I need to calculate the Offline Days as the difference between the Online date in my dataset and the Offline date in the previous row for the same Kiosk.

This is the output that I need in my output dataframe:

| Kiosk | Online | Offline | Online Days | Offline Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/5/2022 | 4 | Nan |
| 1 | 12/7/2022 | 12/17/2022 | 10 | 2 |
| 1 | 12/20/2022 | 12/21/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 12/24/2022 | 12/29/2022 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 11/15/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 15 | Nan |
| 2 | 12/2/2022 | 12/7/2022 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 12/15/2022 | 12/25/2022 | 10 | 8 |
| 3 | 10/30/2022 | 11/15/2022 | 16 | Nan |
| 3 | 11/17/2022 | 11/22/2022 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 11/23/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | 12/4/2022 | 12/15/2022 | 11 | 4 |
| 3 | 12/18/2022 | 12/20/2022 | 2 | 3 |

**Dataframe to start with :**

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'Kiosk':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                 'Online':["12/1/2022", "12/7/2022","12/20/2022", "12/24/2022","11/15/2022", 
                           "12/2/2022","12/15/2022", "10/30/2022","11/17/2022", "11/23/2022",
                           "12/4/2022", "12/18/2022"],
                 'Offline':["12/5/2022", "12/17/2022","12/21/2022", "12/29/2022","11/30/2022", 
                            "12/7/2022","12/25/2022", "11/15/2022","11/22/2022", "11/30/2022",
                            "12/15/2022", "12/20/2022"],
                 'Online Days':[4, 10, 1, 5, 15, 5, 10, 16, 5, 7, 11, 2],
                 })
```

Comment: please give dataframe in the future ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) align `Offline` dates and subtract from `Online` dates and then use [`.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to empty on when the `Kiosk` changes [or to remove negative differences].

```py
# df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962581')[0]
# df[['Online','Offline']] = df[['Online','Offline']].applymap(pd.to_datetime)

offline_days = df['Online'] - df['Offline'].shift(1)
df['Offline Days'] = offline_days.where(df['Kiosk']==df['Kiosk'].shift(1))
# df['Offline Days'] = offline_days.where(lambda td: td>pd.Timedelta(0))
```

[image: opdf]

Comment: Thanks for your solution Driftr95!

Answer (score 1):

I took into account Mozway comment, so I propose you instead the following code (I didn't see you want it by kiosk) :

```py
df['Online'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Online'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Offline'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Offline'], infer_datetime_format=True)

df['Offsets'] = (df['Online'] - df.groupby('Kiosk')['Offline'].shift(1)).dt.days
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
    Kiosk     Online    Offline  Online Days Offsets
0       1 2022-12-01 2022-12-05            4     NaT
1       1 2022-12-07 2022-12-17           10  2 days
2       1 2022-12-20 2022-12-21            1  3 days
3       1 2022-12-24 2022-12-29            5  3 days
4       2 2022-11-15 2022-11-30           15     NaT
5       2 2022-12-02 2022-12-07            5  2 days
6       2 2022-12-15 2022-12-25           10  8 days
7       3 2022-10-30 2022-11-15           16     NaT
8       3 2022-11-17 2022-11-22            5  2 days
9       3 2022-11-23 2022-11-30            7  1 days
10      3 2022-12-04 2022-12-15           11  4 days
11      3 2022-12-18 2022-12-20            2  3 days
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you should use `groupby.shift` with a step of `1` (not `-1`). Then you can remove the `apply`.

Comment: Hi Mozway thank you for your vigilance, you are right

Comment: It's still incorrect. You must use `groupby` to avoid any side effect. Let me write an answer to show it.

Comment: We cross-posted, now it's correct. I'll delete my answer ;)

Comment: Also OP wants the days so you can add `.dt.days`.